# Mapserver and Tilecache configuration issue

Tags: mapserver, mapnik, tilecache

Currently I am using **mapnik2** with **tilecache** for map generation. As there is shift in some of the tiles generated,I am trying to configure **mapserver** with tilecache for caching tiles. I have installed **mapserver 6.2.1** and **tilecache 2.11**. In the **tilecache.cfg** file , I configure as below to access map data:

```
[Layername]
type=MapServerLayer
bbox=255923,904698,1050731,1437039
data_extent=255923,904698,1050731,1437039
layers=layer1,
mapfile=/path to mapfile/
srs=EPSG:32643
```

When I check if tiles are generated by using the url:

http://tilecache.org/docs/README.html

an xml file is generated with error being,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException code="LayerNotDefined">
msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. Invalid layer(s) given in the LAYERS parameter. A layer might be disabled for this request. Check wms/ows_enable_request settings.
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
Cache-Control: max-age=10, must-revalidate
Content-type: text/plain

An error occurred: msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. Invalid layer(s) given in the LAYERS parameter. A layer might be disabled for this request. Check wms/ows_enable_request settings.
  File "/var/www/tilecache/TileCache/Service.py", line 343, in cgiHandler
    format, image = service.dispatchRequest( params, path_info, req_method, host )
  File "/var/www/tilecache/TileCache/Service.py", line 208, in dispatchRequest
    return self.renderTile(tile, params.has_key('FORCE'))
  File "/var/www/tilecache/TileCache/Service.py", line 138, in renderTile
    data = layer.render(tile, force=force)
  File "/var/www/tilecache/TileCache/Layer.py", line 444, in render
    return self.renderTile(tile)
  File "/var/www/tilecache/TileCache/Layers/MapServer.py", line 50, in renderTile
    wms.loadOWSParameters(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mapscript.py", line 1770, in loadOWSParameters
    def loadOWSParameters(self, *args): return _mapscript.mapObj_loadOWSParameters(self, *args)
```

Please help me in solving this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess that `layers=layer1,` is not what you wanted.

Comment: I changed code to 'layers = layer1',but the error still exists.

Comment: Hi I checked map rendering which is currently by mapnik. I checked whether lat,lon values of point data in my database is same as that shown in the map. By testing I found out that point shown in the map is wrong and that in database is right. Is there a way to correct the mapnik's shift of point data in the map.Thanks in adance.

Comment: Can you give an example of coordinates? Maybe the srs:32643 is ignored by mapnik.

Comment: Hi, the lon-lat values of one of my point data stored in postgis database is (686211.905776594,976780.153872843). But in map display the lon-lat value becomes (686522.74817,976713.34693). In the tilecache.cfg and mapnik xml file, srs is denoted as "srs=EPSG:32643". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try rendering in EPSG:900913 to see if that is correct? I'm not sure if mapnik does other CRS right. In my mapnik configuration, srs4326 and srs900913 is defined as proj string in inc/entities.xml.inc, but nothing else. See also http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2012/07/using-custom-projections-with-tilecache.html

Comment: Hi Andre thank you for ur suggestion. I tried to render the map in epsg:900913 project, but map is not rendered.

Comment: OK, so it is probably mapnik that has a problem. I suggest to install the toolchain Openstreetmap uses, and try to get their style working. You don't have to import the whole world into postgis for that, Geofabrik has small extracts for testing. Once that is working, you can try rendering in other CRS. Mapnik can run without tilecache, just start generate_tiles.py with a bounding box for your data area.

Comment: Hi Andre, my project is for a viewing governemnt offices and institutions in a map interface. They have given us the shapefiles for displaying in the map. So using openstreet toolchain won't be apprpriate. In our previous projects we used mapserver and kamap for map creation. As kamap has become primitive, we tried to implement mapserverusing tilecache, but it is displaying error as I have posted earlier. Could you please tell me how to implement mapserver and tilecache? If there is any better options please do tell me. I am using geodjango in my application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use mapserver, tilecache and geodjango.